# RealMatrix doesnt like big numbers

Tags: java, matrix, apache-commons-math

In order to perform a LU Decomposition with [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/), I implemented the following :

The original matrix as a `double[][]` :

```
A matrix :
1.9720119421779572E-13 -1.5495666760275814E-12 
8.940570999398516E-6 1.1377963306426943E-6
```

The operation of `RealMatrix` creation as [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) refers:

```
RealMatrix A_Rmatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(A_matrix);
```

And the final results :

```
A_RMatrix : 
{0; -0}
{0.0000089406; 0.0000011378}
```

I understand that `RealMatrix` doesnt like "big numbers". I found that matrix dimensions are limited to (64, 64).

The problem is "big numbers" are not supported. How can I handle them?

Comment: Those numbers aren't very big, I'd even say *small* ;) Anyway, what's your question?

Comment: How to support big (or small, iyo) numbers?

Comment: Actually, there is an issue. But it is not linked with format. I still search for an answer but not in the scope of this post. Thank you @nustyx